# How to Print a JSON object to Console in Unreal Engine 4 with VaRest Plugin

Tags: json, unreal-engine4

I am trying to print out my response JSON object to my screen in Unreal Engine 4 with the VaRest plugin. I have the bubble code that should work but it is not giving me what I want. Anybody know how to do this in bubble code or in text-based code. Thanks

Pictures
[First Half of Bubbles](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8oETH.png)

[Second Half of Bubbles](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sOKQo.png)

Comment: Hi There. Try adding code to better explain your case.

Comment: It is the bubble code visible in the pictures.

Comment: Code samples from images are frowned upon on Stack Overflow.